# Drawing a simple cube with python

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to draw a simple cube with python.
something like this:

Input:
width: 20
height: 10
depth: 3

Output:

```
`   :::::::::::::::::::/
  :::::::::::::::::::/+
 :::::::::::::::::::/++
####################+++
####################+++
####################+++
####################+++
####################+++
####################+++
####################+++
####################++
####################+
####################`
```

I've tried this

```
breedte = int(input())
hoogte = int(input())
diepte = int(input())

spatie = " "
aantal_spaties = diepte
aantal_plusjes = diepte


for l in range(diepte):
    print(aantal_spaties * spatie + (breedte - 1) * ":" + "/" + l * "+")
    aantal_spaties -= 1

for i in range(hoogte):
    lijst = breedte * "#"
    if i > (hoogte - 1) - diepte:
            aantal_plusjes -= 1
    lijst += + aantal_plusjes * "+"
    print(lijst)
```

But when the depth is greater than the height its doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? What is the expected output and what is the output you get instead?